# How to make emotion component selector work in nextjs app using styled from @mui/material?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I have this codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-boyd-9z2r9?file=/pages/index.tsx

I'm having trouble with a component selector, as in, if I use styled from `@mui/material`, I get this error `Error: Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with @emotion/babel-plugin`. But if I use styled from `@emotion/styled`, it works fine.

There is also a related issue that has been closed: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27380
No clue on how to re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is now documented at https://mui.com/system/styled/#how-to-use-components-selector-api. As the error states, you need to use `@emotion/babel-plugin` and configuration available at the provided link. You'll then be able to use components as selectors. Here's an example:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
// or
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const Child = () => <div/>;

const Parent = styled("div")({
  [`&:hover ${Child}`]: {
    background: 'black',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `@emotion/babel-plugin` and configure it to work with the imports coming from `@mui/material`. See https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27380#issuecomment-928973157